# Why was my question closed without an explanation?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

For some reason my question ([How do I make my bathroom sink easier to clean](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25041/how-do-i-make-my-bathroom-sink-easier-to-clean)) was closed with nothing more than a sarcastic remark from one of the closers. So allow me to offer a defense up front: Under "We welcome these topics" in the FAQ, it says "Which tools and materials to use for a specific task."

Why was this question closed?
How can I improve the question so it can be reopened?

Comment: Duplicate question ([can I apply something to my bathroom counter to make it easier to clean](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25148/can-i-apply-something-to-my-bathroom-counter-to-make-it-easier-to-clean)) asked, and closed.

Comment: The "sarcastic remark" (comment) was removed by a mod, not the comment owner.

Answer (score 3):

I would vote to reopen. The question is about how to modify furniture, and we talk about surface treatments a lot--stain, paint, sanding, etc.

Answer (score -3):

The "task" in this case is not a home improvement task, its a cleaning task. Glossy or matte, all surfaces need to be cleaned, and even high-gloss surfaces like glass can be difficult to clean after enough gunk has built up.  The original question did not mention the surface type or what type of cleaning solutions were being used - if you use just water, any surface will be difficult to clean.

While the comment I left might have been sarcastic, there was some truth to it - surfaces are easier to clean if you clean then more frequently.

Comment: [Plastic wrap](http://www.saranbrands.com/saran-wrap/) is the answer.  If you wrap almost anything in plastic wrap it becomes easier to clean, because all you have to do is remove the plastic wrap.

Comment: Cleaning *may* be on topic, as there are currently 119 questions tagged [tag:cleaning].

Comment: I would argue that "cleaning" is part of maintenance, and thus *should* be on topic here.

Comment: Only if that cleaning has to do with a major appliance or something significant to your house (siding, concrete, etc.)  Cleaning a counter sounds to me like it is in the same scope of small appliances

Comment: Your logic is broken Steven. If I ask "What's the best way to mount my basketball hoop to my garage", the task is the mounting itself, not the ultimate goal of playing basketball. Similarly, I did not ask a question on how to do the task of "cleaning", even if easier cleaning is my final goal. Regardless, the FAQ says nothing about "cleaning" or "maintenance" questions being off-topic.

Comment: And if the problem was that I didn't provide enough info, such as the surface type of the counter, well, that's what the comment section is for. Rather than closing the question, ask for more info. I'd expect that you come across this issue all the time -- people who don't know much about the task at hand often don't know exactly what info you need. On Stackoverflow, amateur programmers are constantly asking questions without providing enough info. So we ask for the info we need, and they learn to get better at providing it off the bat -- like what has happened in questions you yourself asked.

Comment: Finally, just because your comment was truthful doesn't mean it was helpful or relevant. Tester101's comment here is true as well. Care to defend it?

Comment: I have no interest in continuing this discussion.  I hope someone else is able to answer your question should it be re-opened.

Comment: @maxedison What's done is done, the question was closed (whether by mistake or not, no longer matters).  Please provide the requested information (counter material), and allow the community to decide if the question should be reopened. There is a system in place to handle situations like this, but it cannot work without **your** help. You can rant and argue until you are blue in the face, but nothing can be done until you edit your original question.